# Inject ViewModifier to SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, viewmodifier

**Current Situtation**
I work on an iOS SDK containing several `UIViewControllers` that can be customized through a delegate function passing a `String` as the identifier and getting a customized `CALayer`. With that, the host application can customize how the SDK looks.

This is an example:

```swift
extension ViewController: NINChatSessionDelegate {
    func ninchat(_ session: NINChatSession, overrideLayer assetKey: CALayerConstant) -> CALayer? {
        switch assetKey {
        case .ninchatPrimaryButton:
            let layer = CALayer()
            layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            layer.masksToBounds = true
            layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
            return layer
        default:
            return nil
    }
}
```

**Problem**
Nowadays, I'm trying to migrate the code to SwiftUI and Combine. But I cannot find a way to offer  host applications to inject their own attributes. As far as I have understood, a `ViewModifier` struct is used to apply custom attributes to one or multiple `View(s)` in SwiftUI. However, I could not yet find a way to inject them to the SDK because a `ViewModifier` protocol **has Self or associated type requirements**

I appreciate any helps and guides.

Comment: If i get your point correctly, it may be good to look and consider how `ButtonStyle` protocol works in SwiftUI itself.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle

Comment: @MrAlirezaa Thanks for the hint, but it doesn't answer my problem. The question is about _injecting_ custom configurations while all available protocols have some sort of **Self or associated type requirements**